# Virtualbox Mirror IP addresses on adapter

Tags: networking, virtualization, virtualbox

I am currently trying to set up my virtual machine so that the IP addresses inside it are identical to the host's IPs. The reason why I am trying to do this is because I have set up Plesk panel on my Windows virtual machine and I need it to see the exact same IP addresses on the outside, with the same allocation (i.e. 178.11.11.13).

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but your question doesn't explain why you would.

Restating the question: You want two machines on the network with the same address.

You can only have one active at a time. While the virtual is up you won't be able to use the host on the network unless you change the address temporarily instead of just removing the address. Some IDS systems, smart switches and routers will complain about the MAC address changing. You may need a few seconds delay while "moving" the address between machines.

Use a script to drop or change the address of the physical host's NIC before you bring up the virtual (bridged) to the same address.

You'll probably want another script to shutdown or suspend the virtual client and reset the address on the physical host's NIC.